# Error running flask on local GAE server [Errno 13]

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

Trying to run Kamal Gill's [flask-appengine-template](https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template) on the GAE dev server on Windows. Get this error when trying to GET a page. Already tried re-installing both Python and App Engine.
Couldn't find any similar problem by googling. Help me, StackOverflow, you're my only chance.

```
2012-06-18 19:36:29 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8081', 'C:\\Users\\Roman Levin\\Documents\\webapps\\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\\src']"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._code is deprecated. Use OperationResult._code instead.
  'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._CODES is deprecated. Use OperationResult._CODES instead.
  'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))
WARNING  2012-06-18 16:36:31,108 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
WARNING  2012-06-18 16:36:31,325 datastore_file_stub.py:518] Could not read datastore data from c:\users\romanl~1\appdata\local\temp\dev_appserver.datastore
INFO     2012-06-18 16:36:31,421 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:647] Running application dev~myflaskonappengineapp on port 8081: http://localhost:8081
INFO     2012-06-18 16:36:31,421 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:649] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8081/_ah/admin
ERROR    2012-06-18 16:39:41,960 wsgi.py:189] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 225, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\Roman Levin\Documents\webapps\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\src\application\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import urls
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\Roman Levin\Documents\webapps\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\src\application\urls.py", line 11, in <module>
    from application import views
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\Roman Levin\Documents\webapps\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\src\application\views.py", line 20, in <module>
    from forms import ExampleForm
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\Roman Levin\Documents\webapps\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\src\application\forms.py", line 11, in <module>
    from flaskext import wtf
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\Roman Levin\Documents\webapps\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\src\flaskext\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\Roman Levin\Documents\webapps\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\src\pkg_resources.py", line 2646, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet()
  File "C:\Users\Roman Levin\Documents\webapps\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\src\pkg_resources.py", line 397, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Roman Levin\Documents\webapps\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\src\pkg_resources.py", line 412, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "C:\Users\Roman Levin\Documents\webapps\kamalgill-flask-appengine-template-c409e3c\src\pkg_resources.py", line 1694, in find_on_path
    for entry in os.listdir(path_item):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 620, in __call__
    raise OSError(errno.EACCES, 'path not accessible', path)
OSError: [Errno 13] path not accessible: 'c:\\python27\\dlls'
INFO     2012-06-18 16:39:42,016 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 2):

I never used Kamal Gill's repo but I usually use [blossom's Flask GAE skeleton](https://github.com/blossom/flask-gae-skeleton). It is easier to use. Simply, change the app identifier, point you google app engine to the gae folder and you're basically set.

Comment: It's based on the 2.5 runtime and isn't threadsafe. I can probably hack on it a bit, but it hasn't been maintained in a year and that's kind of discouraging.

Comment: to migrate to 2.7 runtime
in boot.py
we no longer use the cgi handler

last line is just: 
`app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)`

and in app.yaml we specify 

`'script: boot.app'`

instead of 

`'script: boot.py'`

the skeleton will work. hope it helps

Comment: here's the complete repo for Flask on python 2.7 runtime. It is already threadsafe https://github.com/femmerling/Flask-GAE-py27

Answer (score 1):

Good to see I am not crazy. About two weeks ago I had this same error when trying to use this exact same template.  In the end, since I am just starting with Python, I actually went back to using the following resources to piece it together myself instead of using the pre-built templates.  Are you by chance running this inside of virtualenv? I don't have this all in a formal write up yet, but using the following resources I was able to get Flask, GAE, and Eclipse/PyDev to play nicely on Windows.

**Instructions for 2.6**
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/60323-python-on-google-app-engine-creating-blog-engine/

**Migrating GAE projects from 2.6 to 2.7**
http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe

Comment: Additionally... Making PyDev for with GAE in Eclipse
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse
http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-python-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/
* one thing to remember when setting up the environment is to make sure that any Eclipse paths should be surrounded by quotes. Eg. "{project_loc}" and not {project_loc}

Comment: Will take a look, but it's not simply a Windows thing. Works fine on another Windows machine I have.

Comment: I have been working on a Windows XP with it working, as soon as I took that project to a 64 bit windows 7 machine it seems to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Using the 64 bit python fixed it.